# Sequence current value changed to its previous value without reset in sql

Tags: sql

I have primary key field with sequence

Restart sequence shows *1*
Current value is `189`

But I have already inserted a record with `194` into the table. So Primary key violate.
Abnormal behavior of sequence.

Can you please help me to understand why sequence goes previous value?
I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: or SQL server 2012+ because it has sequence too.

Comment: DB2 has sequences and generated column values too!

Comment: In table definition there will "Identity Increment" for primary key column to some thing less than the difference of 194 and 189. I normally set it to 1 so every new record increments it by one.

Comment: Not Identity column , I am using sequence to insert in primary key column .